# LINK : fatal error LNK1104

Tags: c++, linker

First of all, I'm new to C++

The problem I'm occuring while trying to build is this:

> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\Users\RoyB\Desktop\GUNZ\SERVER\Source\SafeUDP\lib\SafeUDPd.lib'

This is my Linker:

[image: This is my Linker:]

This is the folder:

[image: This is the folder:]

For some reason it is looking for SafeUDP**d**.lib while the folder only contains a SafeUDP.lib, I don't know why it is doing that.

I've tried copying the file and changing the name of it to SafeUDP**d**.lib

This seem to work however then it goes on to the next folder and does the exact same with this **d** at the end of the file name. Can someone tell me why it is doing that?

Thanks.

Comment: Where do get the SafeUDPd.lib? Maybe you should recompile it with **debug** build. Usually, SomeLib.lib is used for **release** build, when SomeLib**d**.lib is used for **debug** build.

Comment: Did you even read the tag wiki for your tag "hyperlink"? It's about web links. Not sure how it's relevant for this question. Also please use proper formatting and don't link screenshots - instead paste the contents if need be. Provide a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if possible.

Comment: Lol I never put hyperlink in there. I put link but probably auto correct took over.

Comment: The linker looks for the debug version because you are building in debug mode, but you only have a library to build in release mode.

Comment: @stefaanv So if I don't build in debug mode the problem should be fixed?

Comment: I would think so based on the information you give in your question.  It's easy enough to try.